# mysql/PHP: updating empty int field inserts value of 0

Tags: mysql, integer

I have run into a quirk in MYSQL that is proving to be very vexing.

I am updating an existing record using a sql statement.  All the updates work fine except when it gets to zip code, if the value for the zip is empty, it inserts a 0.  If the field does have a value it inserts the correct value without any problem.

The datatype for the zip field is int(11).

Here is sql statement in query:

```
$sql= "UPDATE memberinfo SET firstname = '$firstname', lastname = '$lastname', zipcode='$zipcode', emailadr='$emailadr' WHERE memberid= '$memberid'";
```

When you echo that out before updating if zipcode is empty, it shows `zipcode = '',`

The 0 is getting inserted by MYSQL in response to something or another.

I tried removing the apostrophes around the zip value and MYSQL threw an error so that is not a fix.

Has anyone run across this or can you suggest a solution?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: It has to enter a zero because you set the type to int. to get around that, change the type to varchar, and allow it to be null

Comment: The field is null before the update..because the records are initially created without specifying a zipcode value.  Is it customary to make zipcodes varchar fields?

Comment: i make zipcode fields varchar because some people add dashes or letters to their zip. and with int, it wont work. if you want it to be int, but a blank value. dont update zip='' ,just leave that out.

Comment: @Johnny Craig: In what country zipcodes have letters? PS: I personally prefer to ask person to input data in expected format, rather than giving the ability to insert some garbage

Comment: well some people insert a long zip, such as 90036-0244. and in other countries, such as canada, zips contain letters.

Comment: In many countries, postcodes have letters (Americans call postcodes ZIP codes, for some reason; most places don't). Even in the USA, they may contain hyphens, as @JohnnyCraig demonstrated. And even if they're purely numeric, they're textual data: you aren't doing maths on them, so store them as characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$sql= "UPDATE memberinfo SET firstname = '$firstname', lastname = '$lastname', zipcode=" . (!$zipcode ? 'NULL' : (int)$zipcode) . ", emailadr='$emailadr' WHERE memberid= '$memberid'";
```

In this case - if `$zipcode` is empty (empty string or 0) - `NULL` will be inserted, and the actual value otherwise

PS: make sure your `zipcode` field is NULLable

PPS: now you get `0` because mysql casts empty string to integer and that's 0

Comment: This is a good answer.  I think I am going to change to varchar, however, for the reasons Johnny suggested above.  The UK and Japan also have letter zips..

Comment: This won't work, because it wants to save the literal string `NULL`, not a null value. If you remove the quotation marks around the zipcode value, it'll work.

Comment: @TRiG single quote characters is a required part of php syntax for a string literal. Please check once again, it's all fine :-) If you don't believe me - simply run statement and check the `$sql` variable contents afterwards.

Comment: Ah, you're tricking me by enclosing your string literal in double quotes and using interpolated variables. I never code in that style myself.

Comment: @TRiG I personally don't do that either - I either use prepared statements (for sql) or `sprintf` for arbitrary strings, but in this case I just "fixed" the OPs original code, which does use interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an empty string, when inserted into an INT filed will be treated as 0.  If you are truly using INT and want the default filed value to be insert (or a NULL value to be inserted if allowed by field settings), then you should not put single quotes around the zip code value, but rather change up you query logic to inset value of zipcode=NULL or exclude that filed from the insert altogether.

Answer (score 0):

This is old but I was struggling with this issue using bind_para statements and did want to change int to varchar in mysql.  So I wrote a little helper function that converted the empty string to null.  I go the idea when I was researching a similar problem sending empty strings to date variables
This is the simple function that is called from the array that is used to set up the bind parameters

```
function nullEmptyInt($inputVal){
    if($inputVal == '' || empty($inputVal)){
        return null;
    }else{
        return (int)($inputVal);
    }
}
```